# I believe i was hacked

Tags: 13.04

I have recently started using Ubuntu and have enabled few basic access to the system such as ssh and sftp and also a script which emails me when anyone ssh to my system.

Today I got email trigger, that someone from a remote IP address logged in and it was not me. So I want to see how badly has my system got compromised and, mostly, what did they do ?

If I can't pull that information now, what can I do to setup such logging for next time ?

Please feel free to suggest any solution as I am the root and the only user...

Comment: · First thing: are you sure you are root? If you need to enter root password in order to install things and use sudo, then you aren't root, although if so... bad idea, take a look: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=842738 

 · Second thing: Can you please edit your question adding the script you used to email you?

Comment: Can you give more details about the script you used?  Was it logging auth attempts, successful authentications, connection attempts, or what?

Answer (score 3):

If you were hacked, it is then a game of you vs them, whoever has better knowledge of Linux will win out.

Forensics is a complex subject and, sorry to say, if you have to ask you are more likely then not on the short end of the stick.

My advice is to back up your data and reinstall. Then use strong passwords and read up on hardening your servers.

For example, use keys with ssh and disable password authentication.

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Google search Linux forensics

http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/forensic-analysis-live-linux-system-pt-1

Comment: i completely agree with you my friend, i did not know how to track or see what that other user was doing. So all i did was just turned off my network adapter!

Comment: let me follow your links and see if i can pull any information form the system. If you don't mind me asking i mainly use the SFTP to automatically send my photos from my Android to PC so can i have that user account in only right mode and not read there by denying even the user with the right credentials from not accessing the files. Whereas regarding to password my user accounts have 128 bit length password sure they may have done a brute force attack but why all this trouble i am just a ordinary guy. who has nothing to hide. only explanation i have some one was learning hacking

Comment: Well, we are still not sure you were cracked. All the same, use keys if at all possible.